# Error importing 'vscode-languageserver' in a React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, language-server-protocol, docusaurus

I am trying to create a playground using `monaco-editor` and `vscode-languageserver` to show the features of my language server.

However when I try to import 'vscode-languageserver' from a page like the following example

```
//# src/pages/test.js 
const { TextDocument } =  require("vscode-languageserver"); 
console.log(TextDocument.create('a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' ));
```

https://github.com/zkrami/docusaurus-test/blob/master/src/pages/test.js

I get the following errors:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\Rami\git\my-website\node_modules\vscode-languageserver\lib'./node_modules/vscode-languageserver/lib/files.js

Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Rami\git\my-website\node_modules\vscode-languageserver\lib'./node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/lib/pipeSupport.js
```

and please note that if I imported the module in the `docusaurus.config.js` file it works perfectly.

I made a quick example you can try: 
https://github.com/zkrami/docusaurus-test/

Specifications:

```
yarn 1.22.4 
node v10.15.3
OS: Windows
@docusaurus/core: "^2.0.0-alpha.54"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `vscode-languageserver-protocol` package which fulfill my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

`fs` is a Node module and requires Node runtime, you can't use it in the browser.

This is not a Docusaurus issue, you wouldn't be able to use it in any client-side React app.

Comment: I don't attend to use `fs` itself but the `vscode-languageserver` require it for certain functionalities which I am not using.

Comment: in addition I am using the same package in another react-app and it's working well. 
I also tried it with Docusaurus v1 and it worked just fine.

Comment: Do you have a code example of how the client work with the server? It seems like it is not very well documented. Thanks.